# How to handled SQLITE errors such as "has no column named" that are not raised as Exceptions?

Tags: python, sqlite

what is the best way to catch the "errors" from the SQLite DB in Python as they are not considered as exceptions in Python.

The error output after I tried an INSERT OR IGNORE statement where a column did not exist in the DB is as follows

```
('table X has no column named Y,)
```

The following statement is used to execute the query

```
cursor.execute("INSERT...")
```

THe approach I thought of, does not work as a rowcount is not returned when there is an error on the cursor/ query

```
if cursor.rowcount != 1:
                print("##########Error write_DB\n")
```

Is there something else I could do to catch similar erros.

Background: I am inserting multiple rows and I wanted to highlight in a logfile if the insert query was not sucessfull.

Thanks for you advice

Comment: Please expand on "as they are _not_ considered as exceptions in Python" and how the "error output" is captured. Would these be considered errors (and raised as Python exceptions) if it was a normal `INSERT`?

Comment: This error *definitely* is raised as an exception. Show an actual example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can follow the [EAFP approach](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp), use regular `INSERT` (without the "ignore" part) and catch database errors which you can log:

```
try:
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ...", params)
except sqlite3.Error as err:
    logger.error(err.message)
```

Comment: The OP claims such is *not* considered an Exception in Python.

Comment: @user2864740 but, is not it because the OP is using INSERT OR IGNORE..? Thanks.

Comment: I have added an example with error in my answer above which shows that alexce's approach works well. Seems to be the better solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`ON CONFLICT clause`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) clause. This will be part of the SQL statemant and give you a chance to cover for errors in a `CREATE` etc statement.

For INSERT, the actual syntax reads [`INSERT OR IGNORE`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) instead of `INSERT`, other options like abort or rollback can also be found in that link.

[EDIT]

I have also attached an example with error which shows the feasibility of alecxe's answer below. His answer seems to be the better approach:

```
import sqlite3 as lite

con = lite.connect('test.db')

with con:
    cur = con.cursor()    
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Persons(Id INT, Name TEXT)")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Persons VALUES(1,'Joe')")
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO Persons VALUES(1,'Jenny')")

    try:
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Persons VALUES(1,'Jenny', 'Error')")
        self.con.commit()

    except lite.Error as er:
        print 'er:', er.message

#Retrieve data
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Persons")
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print row
```