# Continue executing sql statements if error found python sqlite3

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I have a file containing sql commands and I want to execute the commands given in the file and if any command throws any error then ignore the error and execute the next command.
Here is a sample file:

```
drop table department;
drop table classroom;

create table classroom
    (building       varchar(15),
     room_number        varchar(7),
     capacity       numeric(4,0),
     primary key (building, room_number)
    );

create table department
    (dept_name      varchar(20), 
     building       varchar(15), 
     budget             numeric(12,2) check (budget > 0),
     primary key (dept_name)
    );
```

> For eg. if the classroom table doesn't exists then the drop table command will produce an error and the program will terminate. I want that the program keep running and execute all commands in the file.

The problem I'm facing is that the `create table` command is in multiple lines so I don't know how to execute that.

Comment: Read the entire file into a string, use.. I think it's the `executescript` method on the sqlite connection object?

Comment: Why are you using `VARCHAR` with specified length while it's ignored by sqlite?

Comment: @OlvinRoght I didn't create this file. I'm currently learning sql in my university and this is a practice problem but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

Comment: @Shawn What if there is an error while executing the sql?

Comment: Then you catch it and do something in response?

Comment: @Shawn but then the remaining commands won't be executed.

Comment: @Shawn in the given sample file if i do executescript it will produce error in the first two lines(assuming there are no initial tables) and then it won't execute the remaining commands but I want to execute all the commands

Comment: Then fix your SQL. Sqlite makes it easy: https://sqlite.org/lang_droptable.html

Comment: (There are ways to do what you want in the C API without changing the SQL statements, but I'm not sure if the Python API provides that level of control.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223496/discussion-between-at-in-and-shawn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the sqlite3 [manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects):

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
cur = con.cursor()
with open('PATH_TO_SQL_FILE', 'r') as fp:
    text = fp.read().split(';')
    for command in text:
       try:
           cur.execute(command)
       except sqlite3.Error:
           pass
```

Comment: How will this handle errors? Please read the question carefully.

Comment: Oh my bet. Is this what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816640/how-to-handled-sqlite-errors-such-as-has-no-column-named-that-are-not-raised-a

Comment: No, this is not what I want to do.

Comment: I updated the answer. can you elaborate why this is not what you want to do?

Comment: Take a look at the comments under the question.

Comment: I did and I still do not see why you can't use my solution.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you edited your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sqlite3

#define connection and cursor
connection = sqlite3.connect ('test_db')
cursor =connection.cursor()


command1 ="""create table classroom
    (building       varchar(15),
    room_number        varchar(7),
    capacity       numeric(4,0),
    primary key (building, room_number)
    )"""

cursor.execute(command1)


command2 ="""create table department
    (dept_name      varchar(20), 
    building       varchar(15), 
    budget             numeric(12,2) check (budget > 0),
    primary key (dept_name)
    )"""
cursor.execute(command2)
```

Comment: if you want to add more sql statements then you need to add more commands (command3,command4 etc)

Comment: this will only work for the sample file. I want it to work for any file. Please read the question carefully.

Comment: I don't have any information about the file I want to take the file as input and then execute the sql commands given in it.

Comment: Also I think it will be difficult if you do not have any information about the file...For example if you want to drop a table that does not exist yet...I expect an error message...

Comment: Yes there will be an error message and I want to catch the error and then execute the next command